# Pulling a fast one

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

```
Place   Name                Time
1.      Usain Bolt          2:14:45
2.      Wayde van Niekert   2:31:18
3.      David Rudisha       2:57:25
4.      Noah Ngeny          3:05:36
5.      Hicham El Guerrouj  3:13:10
6.      Daniel Komen        3:26:36
7.      Kenenisa Bekele     3:33:03
```

What is the competition?

---

<sub>This puzzle is part of *[Recycling old answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150)*.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the competition is the

> Double Marathon (84.39km race)

Reasoning

> If you take each athlete's record in their signature event and take the average speed over the distance of a double marathon, you would get the times listed (when rounded to the nearest second).

Example

> Usain Bolt's record for the $100$m race is $9.58$ seconds for an average speed of $10.438$m/s. Doing this average speed for a distance of $84.39$km would give an overall time of roughly $2$ hours $14$ minutes and $45$ seconds.

Other athletes

> Wayde van Niekert - 400m in 43.03 seconds. 
>  David Rudisha - 800m in 1:40.91. 
>  Noah Ngeny - 1000m in 2:11.96 
>  Hicham El Guerrouj - 1500m in 3:26.00 
>  Daniel Komen - 3000m in 7:20.67 
>  Kenenisa Bekele - 5000m in 12:37.35